# Obj-c: Core Bluetooth - API MISUSE: <CBPeripheralManager: 0x28382c6e0> can only accept this command while in the powered on state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm setting up the Peripheral device and its View Controllers to send Bluetooth data - for some reason when I run my app, I receive the following error:

> [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE:  can
>   only accept this command while in the powered on state

No idea why this occurs. Bluetooth is on, and my code appears to be in the correct order.

**ViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        _peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

        [_peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];



    }

    - (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {

        if (peripheral.state == CBManagerStatePoweredOn) {


            self.transferCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

            CBMutableService *transferService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID] primary:YES];

            transferService.characteristics = @[_transferCharacteristic];

            [_peripheralManager addService:transferService];
        }

       if (peripheral.state != CBManagerStatePoweredOn) {

            return;
        }


    }


- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {

    _dataToSend = [_textView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    _sendDataIndex = 0;

    [self sendData];
}

- (void)sendData {

    static BOOL sendingEOM = NO;

    // end of message?
    if (sendingEOM) {
        BOOL didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:[@"EOM" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

        if (didSend) {
            // It did, so mark it as sent
            sendingEOM = NO;
        }
        // didn't send, so we'll exit and wait for peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers to call sendData again
        return;
    }

    // We're sending data
    // Is there any left to send?
    if (self.sendDataIndex >= self.dataToSend.length) {
        // No data left.  Do nothing
        return;
    }

    // There's data left, so send until the callback fails, or we're done.
    BOOL didSend = YES;

    while (didSend) {
        // Work out how big it should be
        NSInteger amountToSend = self.dataToSend.length - self.sendDataIndex;

        // Can't be longer than 20 bytes
        if (amountToSend > NOTIFY_MTU) amountToSend = NOTIFY_MTU;

        // Copy out the data we want
        NSData *chunk = [NSData dataWithBytes:self.dataToSend.bytes+self.sendDataIndex length:amountToSend];

        didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:chunk forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

        // If it didn't work, drop out and wait for the callback
        if (!didSend) {
            return;
        }

        NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunk encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Sent: %@", stringFromData);

        // It did send, so update our index
        self.sendDataIndex += amountToSend;

        // Was it the last one?
        if (self.sendDataIndex >= self.dataToSend.length) {

            // Set this so if the send fails, we'll send it next time
            sendingEOM = YES;

            BOOL eomSent = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:[@"EOM" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

            if (eomSent) {
                // It sent, we're all done
                sendingEOM = NO;
                NSLog(@"Sent: EOM");
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}


- (void)peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    [self sendData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are calling `startAdvertising` immediately after you instantiate the `CBPeripheralManager` instance.  As the error says you must wait until you get the callback with a `CBManagerStatePoweredOn` state indication before you perform any Bluetooth operations.

In fact, it doesn't make any sense to start advertising at that point because you haven't yet defined your service.  You simply need to move the `startAdvertising` call into the `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` method where you set up your service:

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {

    if (peripheral.state == CBManagerStatePoweredOn) {


        self.transferCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

        CBMutableService *transferService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID] primary:YES];

        transferService.characteristics = @[_transferCharacteristic];

        [_peripheralManager addService:transferService];
        [_peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
    }

   if (peripheral.state != CBManagerStatePoweredOn) {

        return;
    }


}
```

Also, as a point of style, I wouldn't access the `_peripheralManager` ivar directly unless you have a good reason.  It is always best to use the setter/getter.  The performance penalty is minuscule and it avoids subtle bugs in the case where the setter/getter has been overridden.